# Test sockets with mocha and sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, mocha.js, sinon

### Background

I am made a small function that emits messages via sockets and I am trying to test it using mocha.

```
const myFun = socket => {

    socket.emit("first", "hello World!");

    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit("second", "hello Moon!");
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit("third", "hello Mars? Venus? I dunno...");
    }, 2000);
};
```

Because I inject the socket dependency into my function which uses it, it is fairly simple to just pass it a fake socket and test if it is called and with which parameters (using, for example, sinon.js).

### Problem

The problem here is that **I don't know when my test ends**. Because `myFun` does not return a promise nor anything I don't know how to tell mocha that I have sent all the messages I wanted and that the test should end.

### Test

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe("myFun", () => {

    const fakeSocket = {
            emit: sinon.spy()
        };

    it("receive first message", done => {

        myFun(fakeSocket);

        setTimeout(() => {
            try{
                expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledThrice;
                done();
            }catch(err){
                done(err);
            }
        }, 3000);
        //we wait 3 seconds because it should be more than enough for all messages to be delivered
    });

});
```

I am using a `setTimeout` with a `try catch` to test the code, which honestly is quite horrible.

### Question

- How can I improve my tests so they don't take X seconds and just end when I receive the last message?
- How do I remake my tests so I don't depend on timers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/fake-timers/) to advance the clock virtually:

```
describe("myFun", () => {
  const fakeSocket = { emit: sinon.spy() }

  beforeEach(() => {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fakeSocket.emit.reset();
    this.clock.restore();
  });

  it('emit first message', () => {
    myFun(fakeSocket);
    expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  });

  it('emit second message after 1000ms', () => {
    myFun(fakeSocket);
    this.clock.tick(1000);
    expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledTwice;
  });

  it('emit third message after 2000ms', () => {
    myFun(fakeSocket);
    this.clock.tick(2000);
    expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledThrice;
  });
});
```

Or without any timers at all (making `setTimeout` synchronously call the callback it gets passed):

```
describe("myFun", () => {
  const fakeSocket = { emit: sinon.spy() }
  const stub       = sinon.stub(global, 'setTimeout').callsArg(0);

  after(() => {
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('should emit three messages', () => {
    myFun(fakeSocket);
    expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledThrice;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to not depend on timers at all?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix see edit (although I'm not sure if that's a proper testing methodology: the code under test _does_ depend on timers, after all)

Comment: I understand that due to the nature I exposed my problem, this solution is a perfect fit. I have therefore upvoted and selected your answer. If however you have the time, could you check another version of this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560495/test-async-function-with-mocha-and-sinon

Answer (score 0):

> How can I improve my tests so they don't take 3 seconds and just end when I receive the last message?

Which message is the last message? Right now you emit three messages, but what if `myFun` is changed to emit four messages? Or four-hundred? Mocha can't know that `myFun` is finished when async is involved unless you tell it.

Perhaps you should `socket.emit('done')` once you have finished emitting all your messages, and then you can wait for that particular emit to mark your test as complete.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is [Sinon fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/fake-timers/).

Fake timers in Sinon allow you to control the output of inbuilt timing functions like the `Date` constructor, and `setTimeout`/`setInterval`.

A basic usage in `mocha` might be something like:

```
let clock;
beforeEach(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

it ('should do a thing', () => {
    //assertion
});

it ('should a thing 1000 ms later'), () => {
    clock.tick(1000);
    //assertion
});

afterEach(() => {
    clock.restore();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to not depend on timers at all?