# Test async function with mocha and sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, mocha.js, sinon

### Background

I am made a small function that emits messages via sockets and I am trying to test it using mocha and sinon:

```
const myFun = socket => {

    socket.emit("first", "hello World!");

    //some random amount of time passes
    socket.emit("second", "hello Moon!");

    //other random amount of time passes
    socket.emit("third", "hello Mars? Venus? I dunno...");
};
```

Using sinon I can pass to my function a fakeSocket:

```
const fakeSocket = {
    emit: sinon.spy()
};
```

And check if I emit or not the messages.

### Problem

The problem here is that **I don't know when my test ends**. Because `myFun` does not return a promise and I don't have a *final* message I don't know how to tell mocha that I have sent all the messages I wanted and that the test should end.

### Test

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const sinon = require("sinon");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe("myFun", () => {

    const fakeSocket = {
            emit: sinon.spy()
        };

    it("receive first message", done => {

        myFun(fakeSocket);

        setTimeout(() => {
            try{
                expect(fakeSocket.emit).to.have.been.calledThrice;
                done();
            }catch(err){
                done(err);
            }
        }, 1000);
        //1 seconds should be more than enough to let the test complete.
    });

});
```

I am using a `setTimeout` with a `try catch` to test the code, which honestly is quite horrible.

### Question

- How do I remake my tests so I don't depend on `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Since your function doesn't return anything, and the amount of time between the `socket.emit()` calls is random, there isn't really a lot you can do. You _might_ be able to stub the code that is causing those random waits, but it would entirely depend on what exactly that code does.

Comment: Since I know I want to call `socket.emit` X times, I could always try my luck with a counter. What do you think?

Comment: You could do that, but be prepared that if your code is faulty, it may not call `socket.emit()` the expected number of times (in which case the test will time out). And likewise, if your code happens to call it `X+1` times, your test might pass while it should actually fail.

Comment: I fail to see another solution :S Perhaps I could mock some of the computations in between?

Comment: It depends on what exactly that code does.

Comment: the problem is that the comments stand for several lines of code that do multiple things. Things I want to abstract away from. Knowing that my last message is always `"hello Mars? Venus? I dunno..."`, is there a way to do do my tests without setTimeout?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that a particular message is always set last, you can instruct Sinon to call a function when that message is emitted. That function can be Mocha's callback function for asynchronous tests:

```
describe("myFun", function() {
  // Extend timeout and "slow test" values.
  this.timeout(3000).slow(10000);

  const fakeSocket = { emit: sinon.stub() }

  it('should emit a certain final message', done => {
    fakeSocket.emit.withArgs('third', 'hello Mars? Venus? I dunno...')
                   .callsFake(() => done());
    myFun(fakeSocket);
  });
});
```

So if `socket.emit()` is called with arguments `'third', 'hello Mars?...'`, Sinon will call a function that calls the `done` callback, signalling to Mocha that the test has completed.

When, for some reason, that particular message isn't emitted, `done` never gets called and the test will time out (after 3s), which is an indication that either the test has failed, or it took more time than expected.

If you don't know what the first argument to `socket.emit()` is going to be for the last message, only the message itself, the test becomes this:

```
it('should emit a certain final message', done => {
  fakeSocket.emit.callsFake((name, msg) => {
    if (msg === 'hello Mars? Venus? I dunno...') {
      done();
    }
  });
  myFun(fakeSocket);
})
```